# Create a smart pointer of a dynamically deduced type?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, smart-pointers

Is it possible to create a pointer of a dynamically deduced type without using an if sequence?

What should I use as a map value type?

```
class Vehicle {
  public:
    virtual void run() =0;
};

// Derived class
class Mustang: public Vehicle {
  public:
    string model = "Mustang";
    virtual void run() {std::cout<<model<<std::endl;};
};

// Derived class
class Ford: public Vehicle {
  public:
    string model = "Ford";
    virtual void run() {std::cout<<model<<std::endl;};
};

std::unordered_map<std::string, std::type_index> m {{"Mustang",typeid(Mustang)},{"Ford",typeid(Ford)} };

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Vehicle> v;
    std::string s{"Mustang"};
    
    v=std::make_unique<m.at(s)>;
    v->run(); //what i want to achieve is print "Mustang"

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please do not remove includes and using declarations from your code before posting it here. It took me more time to add them back than to add what is missing to get desired output ;)

Comment: Template parameters must be known at compile time, they cannot be "dynamically deduced" at runtime. This is fundamental to C++, there are no exceptions, C++ does not work this way.

Answer (score 2):

You can store callables that return a `std::unique_ptr<Vehicle>` in the map:

```
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <functional>

class Vehicle {
  public:
    virtual void run() =0;
    virtual ~Vehicle() {}
};

// Derived class
class Mustang: public Vehicle {
  public:
    std::string model = "Mustang";
    virtual void run() {std::cout<<model<<std::endl;};
};

// Derived class
class Ford: public Vehicle {
  public:
    std::string model = "Ford";
    virtual void run() {std::cout<<model<<std::endl;};
};

std::unordered_map<std::string, std::function<std::unique_ptr<Vehicle>()>> m {
    {"Mustang",[]()->std::unique_ptr<Vehicle> { return std::make_unique<Mustang>();}},
    {"Ford",[]() ->std::unique_ptr<Vehicle> { return std::make_unique<Ford>();}} 
    };

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Vehicle> v;
    std::string s{"Mustang"};
    
    v=m.at(s)();
           //^^---------- note the () to call the function 
           //             that returns the std::unique_ptr
    v->run(); // prints Mustang

    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/hx1Pahav6)

---

This:

```
[]()->std::unique_ptr<Vehicle> { return std::make_unique<Mustang>();}
```

is rather verbose, so you might want to write a helper function:

```
template <typename T> 
std::unique_ptr<Vehicle> create_vehicle() {
       return std::make_unique<T>();
}
```

---

PS: Your `Vehicle` is missing a virtual destructor.